# Mixing SATA & SAS drives on same server for software raid

Tags: software-raid, windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to mix SATA and SAS drives on the same controller?

These are intended to be used these in server 2012 R2 software raid, obviously not mixed in the same array but maybe on the same controller, depending on how many disk controllers the server comes with.

My original intention was a layout like this:
2 x SATA 250Gb mirrored - for Hyper-V partition
4 x SAS software Raid 1+0 - for virtual machines and all data
1 x SATA - for backup purposes

Problem is now it comes to ordering the hardware it seems there is some question as to whether it can support SATA and SAS at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to mix SATA and SAS drives on the same controller?

Yes.

> These are intended to be used these in server 2012 R2 software raid?

Is that a question?  ;-)

> Obviously not mixed in the same array but maybe on the same controller, depending
>   on how many disk controllers the server comes with.

SATA drives on a SAS controller / SAS hostadapter / SAS based RAID card should work just fine.  You probably want to avoid port multipliers though because if a SATA drives dies then that might lock up the multiplier.  If you just use direct connections then mixing them should be fine.

> My original intention was a layout like this: 2 x SATA 250GB mirrored - 
>   for Hyper-V partition 4 x SAS software Raid 1+0 - for virtual machines and
>   all data 1 x SATA - for backup purposes

Backups are good. But I recommend also storing backups off-line or at least elsewhere. This to prevent loss of both originals and backups in the case of fire, flooding, lightning strike, theft, ...

> Problem is now it comes to ordering the hardware it seems there is some question as to whether it can support SATA and SAS at the same time.

It can. I am writing the answer from a desktop with a 3ware 9750 RAID card with both SAS and SATA drives attached to the same card.

FYI: [Link to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/489101/mixing-sata-and-sas-drives-on-same-controller) over on [SU], which was answered by a regular on [SF]. The same answer is true for software RAID. (In fact, if you are going to use SW based RAID and have a HW RAID card, then reflash the RAID card to a target/initiator mode).

Comment: And dont forget the dying raid controller killing all disc partitions - happened here ;) Backup to second computer please.

Comment: Been there. My original setup was RAID 5 with 1TB disks. No URE problems but a dead 3ware 9650. Which no longer was in production when my died but which had a compatible disk format with a 9750. However with SW RAID that should not be a problem.

Comment: Try that: Adaptec 3805 dying. Compatible controller there - sadly all discs had corrupted data. Backups should always go to a separate system, minimum. Copy over ethernet.

Comment: I still need to set up a remote copy. Right now I plug in eSATA drives and do a full (6+ hours) copy of my data partition. Next month I repeat that with a different drive. Fire will still kill everything though since the disks are stored next to my desktop.